# How to extrapolate simple linear regression and get errors for the coefficients in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression

Here is my sample data:

```
x = np.array([19.0, 47.0, 34.6, 23.2, 33.5, 28.2,34.8, 15.8, 23.8])
y = np.array([6.12,3.55, 2.67, 2.81, 5.34, 3.75,3.43, 1.44, 0.84])
pl.scatter(x,y, facecolors='b', edgecolors='b', s=24)
x = x[:,np.newaxis]
a, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(x, y)
pl.plot(x, a*x, 'r-')
pl.xlim(0,50)
pl.ylim(0,7)
```

[image: Resulting plot with linear fit]

You can see in the plot that the linear fit does not reach y=0. How can I find the x-value (i.e. extrapolate the data) at which y=0? And is there a way to get do an error propagation to get the errors for the coefficient?

Comment: Since your linear ft has only one coefficient it reaches y=0 when x=0. The standard error for the coefficient (if that is what yoi mean) depends on the assumptions you make about your data but usually you do not need any "error propagation".

Answer (score 0):

To extrapolate, you just need to pass to plot a longer `y` array.

Just insert `0` to the array after you fit the line.

```
y = np.insert(y, 0, 0)
```

And then pass to plot:

```
pl.plot(y/a, y, 'r-')
```

Comment: I placed x = np.insert(x, 0, 0) after  a, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(x, y) and the line now crosses to x=0 and y=0. I need it to extrapolate to x= # and y=0, not x=0 and y=0.

Comment: I think the causes an extra vaue in the x but not in the y due to this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (9,)

Comment: See EDIT there was a typo.

Comment: y = np.insert(y, 0, 0), pl.plot(y/a, y, 'r-'), this is found in the edit. But this still leads to the line crossing at x=0 and y=0

Comment: Yeah in your original line you are not using the intercept, you can pick the intercept from `lstsq` subtract it to `y/a`

Answer (score 0):

the `statsmodels` package might be easier to use than the relatively low-level `lstsq` function that's in Numpy.  your question is just estimating:

```
y_i = x_i*a + sigma_i
```

therefore `x=0` will always be at `y=0`. you might be expecting your code to be estimating:

```
y_i = a_0 + x_i*a_1 + sigma_i
```

i.e `a_0` is the intercept, and `a_1` is the `x` coefficient.

using `statsmodels` would require pulling in more packages, but has a [much easier interface](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html):

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y))

fit = smf.ols('y ~ x', df).fit()
fit.summary()
```

would print out:

> ```
>                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
> Intercept      2.4528      1.960      1.251      0.251      -2.183       7.088
> x              0.0303      0.065      0.468      0.654      -0.123       0.183
> ```

and you can get `x` where `y=0` via:

```
-fit.params[0] / fit.params[1]
```

giving approx `-81`.  if you really wanted to fix the intercept as zero, you would add `+ 0` to the formula:

```
fit = smf.ols('y ~ x + 0', df).fit()
```

this interface goes against the Python "explicit is better than implicit" rule, but copies the "R" language style [formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html)s and (in my experience) most regressions want to estimate the intercept anyway.

Comment: Is there a typo in there? Because I get the error: Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional for df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y))

Comment: as it says, `x` needs to be a vector, so use your first definition of `x` and before where you turn it into a column with `x[:,np.newaxis]`