# How to get errors for coefficients from a linear regression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression

I've been able to calculate the coefficients of a linear regression. But is there a way to get the associated errors of the coefficients? My code shown below.

```
from scipy.interpolate import *
from numpy import *
x = np.array([4, 12, 56, 58.6,67, 89])
y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 16,18, 19])

degrees = [0,1]       # list of degrees of x to use
matrix = np.stack([x**d for d in degrees], axis=-1)    
coeff = np.linalg.lstsq(matrix, y)[0]     
print("Coefficients", coeff)
fit = np.dot(matrix, coeff)
print("Linear regression", fit)
p1=polyfit(x,y,1)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients for y=a +bx [3.70720668 0.17012128]
Linear fit [ 4.38769182  5.74866209 13.23399857 13.67631391 15.10533269 18.84800093]
```

Errors are not shown! How to calculate the errors?

Comment: this looks very similar to a question you posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58057314/1358308 why not use `statsmodels` as I suggested?  if you want to know the equations so you can calculate them yourself, maybe try one of the many tutorials that are around or the source of a library that does it or maybe try searching on https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: [linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) gives stderr. Is this the Error you're looking for?

Comment: @SamMason I had trouble with statsmodels. Can use it here in this example?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the "predicted" values for y, let's call it y_pred, and compare them to y to get the errors.

```
predicted_line = poly1d(coeff)
y_pred = predicted_line(x)
errors = y-y_pred
```

Answer (score 0):

Althorugh I like the solution of David Moseler, if you want an error to evaluate the goodness of your regression, you could use the `R2 score` (which use the squared error), already implemented in `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

x = np.array([4, 12, 56, 58.6,67, 89]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 16,18, 19])

reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
reg.score(x, y) # R2 score
# 0.7481301984276703
```

If the `R2` value is near 1, the model is a *good* one